# how to start my application autiomaticaly in background when user launches a build-in camera on Android

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I want to write application on Android that starts in background when user launches a built-in camera (it is important: build-in camera, not an application) and do some actions after user makes a photo.
Is it real? If yes, how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if this is possible. There is no mechanism which android provides that causes a broadcast to the system that Camera has been launched. Plus, you cannot modify the contents shown on the screen as the Camera application is in command. The only way out is to have a MediaScanner and FileObserver to check when a new picture is created in DCIM/Camera/ folder and make your app act accordingly

Comment: I don't want to change anything on the screen. I want to show the dialog to user with some question if users answers "yes" I want to start my application in foreground.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. So what u have to do is, have a MediaScanner Activity (kindly google for code), which scan for new contents in DCIM/Camera/ folder of the phones SD card. As soon a new image is found, your activity can then pop a dialog box and based on user input, select an action to be performed